# Symfony2 custom fields in UserBundle

Tags: symfony, bundle, field

I have: Symfony 2, UserBundle (there is no controller, only Entities User, Roles and not used entity Data ).

I want (controller):
$user = $this->getUser(); // return a User object (\UserBundle\Entity\User)
$user->getData(); // there is a custom method in User object that get a data from Database (table UserData, for example)

How can i do that?

Where should be my "getData" function?

Answer (score 0):

Imo, you should override User entity and add oneToMeny to UserData entity.
Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Yep, thats right. But where should be the data load to the object of entity UserData? I mean, how to make a filled object UserData? I guess, that i need a UserDataRepository, but where should be the data load? I think there shoud be an a variable like $dataId in constructor of UserData entity and the repository query. Is that the Symfony way?